# Using tables to categorise resources with

Tags: database, ms-access, filter, database-design

I'm trying to design a database that allows for filtering according to if a specific resource fills certain categories. I've gotten to the point where I can input data that seems to be how it should be filled out but I'm not sure how I should pull it out again.

The main resource table looks like this:

Table1 - resources

```
| resourceID   | AutoNum    |
| title        | short text |
| author       | short text |
| publish date | date       |
| type         | short text |
```

Table2 - Department Categories

```
| ID | AutoNum |
| 1  | Yes/No  |
| 2  | Yes/No  |
| fID| Number  |
```

Table3 - Categories

```
| ID   | AutoNum |
| cat  | Yes/No  |
| dog  | Yes/No  |
| bird | Yes/No  |
| fID  | Number  |
```

I have built a form where you can fill in items to the resource ID, and at the same time check off the Yes/No boxes in tables 2 & 3.

I'm trying to use the primary key ID from table 1 and copy it into the table 2 & 3 with referential integrity to cascade deletes, updates. Which I think is the right way to do this.

Currently, I've learnt that I can implement a search function for the columns in table 1, this seems to work fine. However I am stuck with applying the relevant columns in table 2 and 3 as filters.

apply search>

[X] - Cats

Should only return records from table 1 where in table 3 the relevant column has a tick in the Yes/No box.

I hope I have explained this properly, very new to Access and databases so if you need clarity, don't mind offering.

Comment: there are a few elements that are not clear to me. First of all in the structure of your DB. Then we can look into how to do the filtering / selection. 1) table3: can a record be: cat=true | dog=true | bird=true? logically you would have only one field with different values (e.g. species of type String). This is also a more flexible approach in case requirements are going to change in the future and you will also have to add 'fish'.

Comment: Table3 is not a normalized data structure. I don't even understand purpose of Table2 but it also appears to be non-normalized.

Comment: I was going to ask about Table2 too. It seems the structure of the tables needs some work before proceding. @rfnrf can you please try to explain what you are trying to model?

Comment: @DuncanDrake I am trying to create a set of resources that belong certain categories, and may be relevant to both cats, dogs, birds. And for deptartment 1, 2,3. This is why they are not a list as one resource may be relevant to more than just one dept/category

Comment: Many-to-Many relationship requires a junction table. Each combination of resource/category would be a record in junction table. I am still not sure how Department works into this structure. Perhaps a record for each resource/department/category combination. Or 2 junction tables.

Comment: @June7 The department field is who might be interested in the resources. ie. dept 1 might: filter by dept1, and then filter by dogs, to see which records in resources are relevant to them. I'm not sure what a junction table is, but the way I thought of was that each resource has its own row which matches rows in dept & category tables.  ie one to one. So record 1 in resources table, 1 - Yes (dept table), Yes - Cat (category table), should pop up if someone filters for dept 1 & Cat

Comment: 1-to-1 with non-normalized structure will be more difficult to work with. What if you want to know which resource has department 1 OR 3 AND categories cat OR bird or any other combination of logical operators? You should research database normalization, specifically for many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @June7 I'll look it up, thanks for trying to help though! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try building query joining tables and applying your filter criteria?

Comment: @June7 I haven't tried that no. Would that essentially treat the tables as one very wide tably?

Comment: Yes it would. How else would you expect to filter table1 based on criteria in table3? So if you really want 1-to-1 relationship, no need to separate into 3 tables. I still think you are going down wrong road and will eventually regret it.

Comment: @June7 I think i might have finally explained myself now, sorry about muddying it up. But say I have only the resource table. How would you recommend I go about categorising the resource rows by department and category then?

Comment: Already described in earlier comment. Do research. tblResources, tblDepartments, tblCategories, tblResDept, tblResCat. or one junction table tblResDeptCat. However, I will backtrack a little. The simple filter example you provided would be easy with 1-to-1 data, however, the more complicated example I provided will be difficult if not impossible. It would also be difficult with 2 many-to-many junction tables.

Comment: @rfnrf while I may have not understood the whole model I think you would be better take a look at the entity-relationship model. The way you stated your reply to me it looks like you should model two 1-many relationships. Is fID the foreign key? (Maybe you had better be more explicit with the name). Do Department and Categories share any relation? (aside both being in 1-many relation with resources)

Comment: If each resource can have multiple departments and multiple categories and each department and category can associate with multiple resources, then this is a many-to-many relationship.